# How to speed up sorting of django queryset?

Tags: python, django, sorting, optimization

We have custom User model, each instance has multiple interests.

Here is Interest model:

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                   related_name="interests", blank=True)
```

When user going to page, we suggest to contact with other people who have most common interests relatively to this user.

For generation list of users we use:

```
 def suggested_people(user):
    queryset = User.objects.custom_filter(is_verified=True).exclude(pk=user.pk).order_by('-date_joined').select_related()
    users_sorted = sorted(queryset, key=lambda x: x.get_common_interest(user).count(), reverse=True)
    return users_sorted
```

Method of User-model :

```
def get_common_interest(self, user):
    """ Return a list of string with the interests and the total number remaining """
    your_interests = user.interests.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    return self.interests.filter(pk__in=your_interests)
```

But there is a problem that the list is sorted very slowly (for 1,000 users about 8 seconds). Is it possible to somehow simplify or speed up the sorting?
Will be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have an incoming user named as `u` for which we want to show suggestions, then the query would be:

```
from django.db.models import Count

interests_ids = u.interests.values_list('id', flat=True) # select ids of incoming user interests
suggestions = User.objects
                  .exclude(id=u.id) # exclude current user
                  .filter(is_verified=True) # filter only verified users
                  .filter(interests__id__in=interests_ids) # select users based on common interests
                  .annotate(interests_count=Count('interests')) # count numbers of interests for each user after filtering
                  .order_by('-interests_count') # order users by max common interests
```

The `suggestions` queryset will not contain any user which don't share any common interest with user `u`. If you still want to show some suggestions if there are no suggestions from above query, then you can filter User based on some other criteria e.g. users living in same country or city.